# TNS_ADMIN environment variable

Tags: oracle, client, environment-variables, tnsnames

So I have a client who is deploying multiple versions of oracle in a cross-platform environment. They store their TNS Names file on a network resource. The users will be accessing via Windows 8.1.
There will be both 32 and 64 bit versions of 12c. The client wants to be able to use the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to resolve for TNS names and basically wants this to be a permanent setting for each user who logs on the workstation. I have read numerous articles some say set under HKLM under the environment key some say create it under HKLM and software. Some say HKCU which would only work for the currently logged in user. Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I personally set it through the environment variables, and not the registry. You should be able to add to the global environment variables on that machine. If you do set it in the registry it should be HKLM (Local Machine) as that is the default used by Oracle for the Oracle homes and configuration variables, though Oracle doesn't use the Windows software registry, it keeps track in its own database that is manged through OUI.

A simple way to test is to create a tnsnames.ora file in a nonstandard location, point TNS_ADMIN to it, add an entry (FOO1) and save, then try to tnsping FOO1 from command prompt.

You'll see quickly if the setting is in effect.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but this really doesn't provide a solution for our case. Setting it on the machine is not an option. I figured it was HKLM but is it under HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node, is it under 「HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment, or is it even under 「HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment」. If it is under current user that poses a bigger challenge as we want this done during install. Lastly the value of the key itself I know Unix/Oracle/Java sometimes use the "\\" when it comes to env. variables. Keep in mind also we're talking network location.

Comment: Ok, well the reason I suggested is that your question stated `basically wants this to be a permanent setting for each user who logs on the workstation` so I wasnt sure you were using a profile. So you are using a domain, and want to set this in the user's profile per user or for all users?

Comment: No and that's cool its understood. So basically we used the OUI to generate a response file. We are running a batch file in sccm to kick off the setup.exe in conjunction with the .rsp file. What I was hoping to do was to be able to add a registry key or run a command within the batch which would permanently set the environment variable for tnsnames (TNS_ADMIN) which this actually on a network drive that the user is mapped to automatically as part of the login process. So the tnsnames file basically resides on x:\\sharename\directory\

Comment: Ok, so have you actually tried setting HKLM\Software\Oracle\<Oracle Home>\TNS_ADMIN ? That is where it would go. You should be able to add that after the install finished. Otherwise, I'd probably try adding a script to modify the environment variable. I've done it before with Visual Studio Setup projects, so I know it can be done.